# Why will certain websites not load with CSS, on all browsers, on all my PC's?

Tags: networking, html, web, css

[image: super user ask question page]
[image: stack overflow user profile]
[image: booking.com]

Examples of the webpages not loading properly are shown in the above three images. (superuser ask question page, stackoverflow user profile, booking.com).

Certain websites do not load properly. I have tried using Chrome, IE, Edge, and Firefox, and I have tried doing this on all 3 of my home laptops, and all have the same problem. It is always the same webpages that do this, meaning I just can not use certain web pages. Some of these are Stack Exchange pages. Not all of them, for example I can see my profile of my EE stack exchange page, but I can not properly see my profile on the stack overflow page.

I have also tried disabling all extensions, this also did not work.

- First, what is the best way to describe this problem? I want to ring my ISP but I do not know how to explain it?
- Second, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your network that has content filtering?

Comment: As far as I am aware I just have the windows 10 default firewall. Other security software I use are Avast (free) and Malware bytes (free), but I do not think that either of these have firewalls.
I also highly doubt that I have content filtering as I can access websites that would definitely block.

Comment: If you go to chrome and you press F12 and in the above tabs you go to console what does it say?

Comment: @DylanRz On a webpage that works: http://imgur.com/a/S0xnI .On a webpage that doesn't work: http://imgur.com/UJaCLrV

Comment: Your adblocker may be to blame, but could be a DNS resolving issue with cdn.sstatic.com

Comment: Ye I thought it was a dns problem aswell can you try changing it to google? so 8.8.8.8

Comment: @mveroone Disabling adblock removes some of the errors, but not all of them. And the webpages still load incorrectly. Here is a screenshot without adblock: http://imgur.com/a/IrI9S .

And here with adblock: http://imgur.com/a/qYvgp

Comment: @DylanRz What do you mean by change it to google? And what do you mean by 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @Blue7 Right click your internet connection in the tray -> networkcentrum -> Click Ethernet -> Click Properties -> Click TCP/IPv4 -> And change the DNS-Server

Comment: @DylanRz Just did this (but for wireless as i'm using wifi), and then restarted my connection, but it still has the same problem. The console is also giving the same errors.

Comment: @DylanRz please answer it, DNS change fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem rarely, and used inspect source to look at the errors. Most of them were "HTTPS overflow getting img (insert image name).png/jpeg"

Changed HTTPS to HTTP, worked first-time. Try that!